# Could Armed/Dangerous target an opponent's creature, to force a block with all creatures in play?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Could I target an opponent's creature, then use all creatures from both sides to block that creature, so that Bam! I get rid of something nasty? I think this because the wording on [Dangerous](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=368989&part=Dangerous) says "ALL creatures..."

Comment: Keep reading past the first couple words: "All creatures **able** to block..."

Answer (score 6):

> Could all creatures in both sides block one of my opponent creatures

No. [Dangerous](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=368989&part=Dangerous)'s effect doesn't allow a creature to block creatures it couldn't otherwise block, and one can't block one's own creatures. It merely affect the choice of whether a creature blocks or not, and the choice of what it blocks when it does.

> Could "Armed & Dangerous" could be targeted at a creature my opponent controls?

Yes, but it wouldn't be useful to do so unless it's something like [Illusionary Servant](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Illusionary%20Servant).

The effect would be useless when your target an opponent's creature (except in very obscure situations). For starters, since Dangerous is a sorcery, the opponent wouldn't be able to attack with the creature before the effect ends.

Comment: It actually could be useful to target your opponent for more than illusionary sacrifice. Let's say someone has that effect on a high power deathtouch creature (say revenge of the hunted on deadly recluse?). That's bad because he'll do one damage to each of your creatures since they must block. If you cast Dangerous targeting a weak attacker, you'll be given the choice of which one to block, naturally picking the one that won't kill most of your dudes. He'll still get through with damage, but at least it won't be a board wipe.

Comment: @corsiKa, You appear to have stopped reading too soon, as I addressed that already. Dangerous can't target attackers because it's a sorcery. What you are describing is one of the obscure situations I mentioned. (You need Hypersonic Dragon in play and you need to be attacked by two creatures and one of them must have Lure.)